# How do I complete this PureScript pushState routing example?

Tags: url-routing, purescript

I'm trying to do pushState routing in PureScript, using the `purescript-routing` library. To help work it out, I've built the following minimal example:

```
module Main where

import Prelude

import Data.Foldable (oneOf)
import Data.Generic.Rep (class Generic)
import Data.Generic.Rep.Show (genericShow)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Flame (Html, QuerySelector(..))
import Flame.Application.NoEffects as FAN
import Flame.HTML.Attribute as HA
import Flame.HTML.Element as HE
import Routing.Match (Match, end, int, lit, root)
import Routing.PushState (makeInterface, matches)
import Signal.Channel (send)

type Model = {
  route :: Route
}

data Message = ChangeRoute Route

data Route
  = RouteOne
  | RouteTwo
  | RouteThree Int
  | Root

derive instance genericRoute :: Generic Route _
instance showRoute :: Show Route where
  show = genericShow

route :: Match Route
route = root *> oneOf
  [ Root <$ end
  , RouteOne <$ lit "route-1" <* end
  , RouteTwo <$ lit "route-2" <* end
  , RouteThree <$> (lit "route-3" *> int)
  ]

init :: Model
init = { route: Root }

update :: Model -> Message -> Model
update model = case _ of
  ChangeRoute x -> model { route = x }

view :: Model -> Html Message
view model = HE.main "main" $
  [ HE.p_ ("Route: " <> show model.route)
  , HE.ul_
    [ HE.li_
      [ HE.a [ HA.href "/route-1" ] "route 1"
      ]
    , HE.li_
      [ HE.a [ HA.href "/route-2" ] "route 2"
      ]
    , HE.li_
      [ HE.a [ HA.href "/route-3/123" ] "route 3"
      ]
    ]
  ]

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  nav <- makeInterface

  flameChannel <- FAN.mount (QuerySelector "main")
    { init
    , update
    , view
    }

  void $ nav # matches route \oldRoute newRoute -> do
    log $ show oldRoute <> " -> " <> show newRoute
    send flameChannel [ ChangeRoute newRoute ]
```

What works:

- Route parsing
- Printing the current route in the console

What doesn't work: Clicking a link in the DOM is handled by a page load, instead of a signal being sent to the application.

What code changes/additions need to be made so clicking a link results in a signal being sent to Flame, as opposed to a browser page load? Is my general approach even correct?

I've tried using the [purescript-routing documentation](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-routing/blob/main/GUIDE.md) and [purescript-routing tests](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-routing/blob/main/test/Test/Browser.purs#L111) to gain an understanding, but neither show a complete example (including clickable URLs). I have also tried working from the [RoutingPushHalogenClassic PureScript cookbook code](https://github.com/JordanMartinez/purescript-cookbook/tree/master/recipes/RoutingPushHalogenClassic), but it doesn't seem applicable to Flame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to complete it:

```
module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Foldable (oneOf)
import Data.Generic.Rep (class Generic)
import Data.Generic.Rep.Show (genericShow)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..), isNothing)
import Debug.Trace (spy)
import Effect (Effect)
import Effect.Console (log)
import Flame (Html, QuerySelector(..))
import Flame.Application.NoEffects as FAN
import Flame.HTML.Attribute as HA
import Flame.HTML.Element as HE
import Foreign (unsafeToForeign)
import Routing.Match (Match, end, int, lit, root)
import Routing.PushState (PushStateInterface, makeInterface, matches)
import Signal.Channel (Channel, send)
import Web.Event.Event (preventDefault)

type Model
  = { navInterface :: PushStateInterface
    , route :: Route
    }

data Message
  = ChangeRouteInternal Route
  | ChangeRouteExternal Route

data Route
  = RouteOne
  | RouteTwo
  | RouteThree Int
  | Root

derive instance genericRoute :: Generic Route _

instance showRoute :: Show Route where
  show = genericShow

route :: Match Route
route =
  root
    *> oneOf
        [ Root <$ end
        , RouteOne <$ lit "route-1" <* end
        , RouteTwo <$ lit "route-2" <* end
        , RouteThree <$> (lit "route-3" *> int) <* end
        ]

init :: PushStateInterface -> Model
init nav = { navInterface: nav, route: Root }

update :: Model -> Message -> Model
update model = case _ of
  ChangeRouteInternal x -> spy "ChangeRouteInternal" model { route = x }
  ChangeRouteExternal x -> spy "ChangeRouteExternal" model { route = x }

view :: Model -> Html Message
view model =
  HE.main "main"
    $ [ HE.p_ ("Route: " <> show model.route)
      , HE.ul_
          [ HE.li_
              [ HE.a (routeAnchorAttributes (ChangeRouteInternal RouteOne)) "route 1"
              ]
          , HE.li_
              [ HE.a (routeAnchorAttributes (ChangeRouteInternal RouteTwo)) "route 2"
              ]
          , HE.li_
              [ HE.a (routeAnchorAttributes (ChangeRouteInternal (RouteThree 123))) "route 3"
              ]
          ]
      ]
  where
  routeAnchorAttributes = case _ of
    ChangeRouteInternal anchorRoute -> [ HA.href (routeToUrl anchorRoute), onClick_ anchorRoute ]
    _ -> []

  -- Based on keypress example at:
  -- https://github.com/easafe/purescript-flame/blob/master/test/Basic/EffectList.purs
  onClick_ clickedRoute =
    HA.createRawEvent "click"
      $ \event -> do
          preventDefault event
          model.navInterface.pushState (unsafeToForeign {}) (routeToUrl clickedRoute)
          pure $ Just (ChangeRouteInternal clickedRoute)

routeToUrl :: Route -> String
routeToUrl = case _ of
  Root -> "/"
  RouteOne -> "/route-1"
  RouteTwo -> "/route-2"
  RouteThree n -> "/route-3/" <> (show n)

routeMatch :: Match Route -> Channel (Array Message) -> PushStateInterface -> Effect Unit
routeMatch m chan =
  void
    <$> matches m \oldRoute newRoute -> do
        log $ show oldRoute <> " -> " <> show newRoute
        if isNothing oldRoute then
          send chan [ ChangeRouteExternal newRoute ]
        else
          pure unit

main :: Effect Unit
main = do
  nav <- makeInterface
  flameChannel <-
    FAN.mount (QuerySelector "main")
      { init: init nav
      , update
      , view
      }
  routeMatch route flameChannel nav
```

- This code has separate `Message` concrete types for route changes originating from inside the application versus outside, i.e. from the user typing in the address bar, loading the application from an external link, etc. This is not necessary, but I wanted to highlight that the logic and code paths for these circumstances are different.
- `routeMatch` handles external routing changes, `onClick_` is for internal and uses Flame's own [`createRawEvent`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-flame/0.7.0/docs/Flame.HTML.Event#v:createRawEvent) function.
- While the Flame docs don't cover click handling and `preventDefault`, I did find [this test of key capture](https://github.com/easafe/purescript-flame/blob/master/test/Basic/EffectList.purs) very helpful when making `onClick_`.
- Open the developer tools console to see messages and internal state changes.